# MySQL auto increment jumping by 7 when inserting from my application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, ibm-cloud

I have setted a simple Spring Boot application into bluemix and i am trying to insert some Objects into the MySQL database i configured, but the problem is that when inserting from my application the auto increment id is jumping by 7, this does not happen when i insert diretcly via SQLYog:

I have a simple controller:

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        TesteDAO dao;

        @RequestMapping("/")
        @ResponseBody
        public String hello() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {       
             Teste t = new Teste();
              t.setName("teste");
              t.setLink("teste");
              dao.addArticle(t);
              System.out.println(t.getId());
              return "";
        }


}
```

The entity:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Teste {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
        private int id;  

    @Column(name="post")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="link")
    private String link;


    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }




}
```

The DAO:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class TesteDAO {

    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public void addArticle(Teste t) {
        entityManager.persist(t);
    }
}
```

Heres the result of inserting directly:

```
INSERT INTO test (post, link) VALUES ("test", "tet");
INSERT INTO test (post, link) VALUES ("test", "tet");
INSERT INTO test (post, link) VALUES ("test", "tet");


    id  post    link    
------  ------  --------
     1  test    tet     
     2  test    tet     
     3  test    tet
```

And heres after inserting by my application in a for loop of 10:

```
    id  post    link    
------  ------  --------
     1  test    tet     
     2  test    tet     
     3  test    tet     
     8  teste   teste   
    15  teste   teste   
    22  teste   teste   
    29  teste   teste   
    36  teste   teste   
    43  teste   teste   
    50  teste   teste   
    57  teste   teste   
    64  teste   teste   
    71  teste   teste
```

Comment: Is it possible that the auto increment offset has changed on your MySql server?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61830/changing-mysql-auto-increment-offset

Comment: That would affect both types of insert correct? Why when inserting "by hand" i get the auto increment of 1?

Comment: Correct.  Wondering if this has happened. after your initial 3 inserts.

Comment: Jus tried the manual insertiong and its also increasing by 7 now, so i dont think its related to the application, i tried to change the auto_increment but it looks like i only have read only access

Comment: You might be able to execute the following:  show variables where variable_name = 'auto_increment_increment';

Comment: Yes i figured out the value is set to 7, i was chaging but i only have access to the session_variables so when i setted to 1 i was able to insert manually and get an auto increment of 1, my problem now is how to change it permantly

Comment: @MauroM `SET GLOBAL auto_increment_offset  = 1;`

Comment: Error Code: 1227
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation i dont know how to get access to that in bluemix

Comment: Is this a compose mysql instance you are using on bluemix? https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ComposeForMySQL/index.html

Comment: Yes, its compose: Compose for MySQL-6c